# Vaadin Grid CSS

Tags: grid, vaadin

I want to apply CSS for Vaadin 23 Grid but its not working properly.
I think I am missing syntax

please help me with correct syntax

```java
Grid<>QuestionOutputGrid = new Grid<>(QuestionOutputScore.class);
QuestionOutputGrid.setSizeFull();
QuestionOutputGrid.addClassName("styled");
```

`Vaadin-Grid.CSS`:

```css
[part~='cell'] ::slotted(Vaadin-Grid-cell-Content.styled)
{
    white-space: break-spaces;
}
```

Comment: What is not working properly? Your css not being picked up (where in the project is it located?)? Or is it picked up, but it has not the effect you are looking for? Please be specific.

Comment: The classname is not propagated to the child elements, that is why it is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Tatu mentioned in his comment, *the classname is not propagated to the child elements*, but it's applied to the `td` in the shadow-dom:

[image]

You need to style it as:

```
[part~='cell'].styled ::slotted(vaadin-grid-cell-content)
{
    white-space: break-spaces;
}
```